# What is the closest thing to WordPress in python instead of php?

Tags: php, python, wordpress

What is the closest thing to [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) in python instead of php?

[WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) is known for its simplicity. You donwload it, throw it on your server, make some edits to a config file and you are done. Afterwords you can pick a nice theme and edit it a little bit and voilá your homepage (with blog functionality) is ready.

I wondered if there is a python equivalent to this. I am more skilled in python then in PHP and I like the way you handle things in python better then in PHP. Further more I have little time to read up about a complicated web framework and need something, that works out of the box.

In Detail, I want

1. a simple and proper looking static homepage.
2. to add some Javascript driven Modules to it. Like the [SIMILE Timeline](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/) and Google Maps.
3. to exchange data with a MySQL Server.
4. to have a search form for the database.
5. to display content from the database in proper lists or tables.

What would you recommend?

Comment: Using what metrics? For what purpose?

Comment: Is there also any, that can be used on shared hosting, without SSH access?

Comment: @Selinap, If your host supports python or that specific python framework. Though, it's highly unlikely they do.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is another project worth mentioning not on the Python wiki blog software page, [mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/). Built on top of Django, it certainly angles to be an all encompassing blog solution, and even lets you import your old wordpress posts (if you wanted to migrate). Django is a great project in general, so it gives you a good base to do anything you want.

If you are just interested in throwing together a blog, or a site which will have similarly static content, you might want to check out [hyde](http://hyde.github.com/), which is a static site generator, similar to ruby's jekyll. It's a pretty neat approach.

Comment: I had a look at hyde yesterday. Seams great. I'll give it a try, thank you for the link!

Comment: I think Pelican is also worth mentioning alternative when it comes to static site generators in Python.

Comment: For OP question Mezzanine may be fine but in general terms unfortunately there is nothing even remotely similar to the level of maturity, extensibility, community, number of themes and plugins that Wordpress has but for python.

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure what you are looking for, but here is a list of a bunch of blogging software written in python:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonBlogSoftware

Answer (score 9):

[Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) has many [cms packages](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/cms/) that *could* act as a Wordpress substitute.  Based on the page listing cms packages, I tried out two: [django-cms](https://www.django-cms.org/en/) and [mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/).  These are both active projects and with many projects using them.  So far I'm leaning toward mezzanine: its documentation is better and it is a little easier to set up.

For sure, though, you should [check out this page of comparisons](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/cms/): it will probably be more up to date than the answers here on SO.  But if all you have to go by is this page, I'd say go with mezzanine.